# classify interval Day and Night SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a time frame :

```
FROMTIME:06:01:00 - TOTIME:23:59:00   = DAY
FROMTIME:23:59:01 - TOTIME:06:00:00   = Night
```

I have a TIME_IN and TIME_OUT by a Car .
How to classify interval time by car is DAY or Night or DayAndNight
. I use code but it's execute very long time :

```js
Declare @From_Time_Day time
  ,@To_Time_Day time
  ,@From_Time_Night time
  ,@To_Time_Night time
  ,@Midnight time
  
set @From_Time_Day = (select FROM_TIME from DAY_STATUS where DAY_CHECK=1)
set @To_Time_Day = (select TO_TIME from DAY_STATUS where DAY_CHECK=1)
set @From_Time_Night = (select FROM_TIME from DAY_STATUS where DAY_CHECK=2)
set @To_Time_Night = (select TO_TIME from DAY_STATUS where DAY_CHECK=2)
set @Midnight = '00:00:00'

select * from (
select 
 (case when ( 
    cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as date)
    = cast(Data.IO_TIME as date)
    )
    then 
    (
    case when (
         cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as time) >= @From_Time_Day
         and cast(Data.IO_TIME as time) <=@To_Time_Day
              ) then 'DAY'    
         when (
               cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as time) >= @From_Time_Night
               and cast(Data.IO_TIME as time) < @Midnight
        ) then 'Night'
      when (
            cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as time) >= @Midnight
         and cast(Data.IO_TIME as time) <= @To_Time_Night
           ) then 'Night'   
     else 'DayAndNight' end
    ) 
    when  (
    cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as date)
    <> cast(Data.IO_TIME as date)
    )
    then (
    case when(
       (cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as time) >= @From_Time_Night and 
       cast((select top 1 IO_TIME from IO_INFO where IO_STATUS= 'IN' and CA_ID = Data.CA_ID and IO_ID < Data.IO_ID order by IO_ID desc) as time) < @Midnight)
       and (cast(Data.IO_TIME as time)>=@Midnight and cast(Data.IO_TIME as time)<=@To_Time_Night)
             ) then 'Night'
        else 'DayAndNight' end
          ) 
   end
) as INTERVAL 
from IO_INFO as Data where IO_STATUS = 'OUT'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seeing that this is a Tricky type of query I've lost some time to find a solution, I've Created a Table in a test database with 4 fields, ID, Car, TimeOut, TimeIn, I've inserted some rows in this table to have samples and then I've made a Query that returns the state of the period for each travel of my cars.

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Car]
  ,[TimeOut]
  ,[TimeIn]
  , MultiDay
  ,OutDAyNight
  ,InDAyNight
  , CASE WHEN Multiday = 1 THEN 'Day/Night'
        WHEN OutDAyNight+InDAyNight = 1 THEN 'Day/Night'
        WHEN OutDAyNight+InDAyNight = 2 THEN 'Day'
        WHEN OutDAyNight+InDAyNight = 0 THEN 'Night' END AS    Periods 
FROM 
(SELECT [ID]
          ,[Car]
          ,[TimeOut]
          ,[TimeIn]       
          , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, [TimeOut],[TimeIn]) > 18 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MultiDay    
          , CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [TimeOut]) > 6 AND 
               DATEPART(hour, [TimeOut]) <=23 THEN 1
               WHEN DATEPART(hour, [TimeOut]) = 6 AND 
               DATEPART(minute, [TimeOut]) > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END AS OutDAyNight      
          , CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [TimeIn]) > 6 AND 
               DATEPART(hour, [TimeIn]) <=23 THEN 1
               WHEN DATEPART(hour, [TimeIn]) = 6 AND 
               DATEPART(minute, [TimeIn]) > 0 THEN 1        
               ELSE 0 END AS InDAyNight       
          FROM [dbo].[TbCarInOut] ) Times
```

Using this double query, In the first select (the lower one in the script) I Used the Datediff function to see if the time between exit and return of the car is more than 18 hours, this surely means there is a day and night period. Then I use the Datepart function to understand if the out time is Night or Day setting a 0 for Night and 1 for day and I do the same for the time In, this way, in the second query, I can use a simple case and a sum to decide if the period is Day/Night, Day or Night.
HTH